# Tangent with $2$ circles

Tags: geometry

I have this $2$ circles with a tangent (see the pic below), and the $R = 9$ (big circle) and $r = 4$ (small circle). I need to find the length of AB (the tangent).

In the hint they say draw the radius for each circle, ok I did. And I know I need to use Pythagorus some how, but could see where..please give me another hint..

[image]

tnx

Comment: Try to see that the quantity $x$ you're looking for must satisfy $x^2 + (R-r)^2 = (R+r)^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw the line segments $MA$, $MN$ and $NB$. Drop a perpendicular from $N$ onto $MA$. Say the foot of the perpendicular is $D$. Try to compute the length of $ND$ and relate that to length of $AB$.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Here's your **BIG HINT**. You have $(x+y)$ and $(x-y)$. Use [Pythagoras Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) to find AB.

Comment: It is a big hint. But +1 :-)

Comment: @user804968: You got the answer. I'm glad. Do work more problems on tangents.:)

Comment: @Aryabhata: The figure makes it big.;).Not to forget your batman graphs!

Comment: ${}{}{}{}{}$:-)

Comment: @Aryabhata: Sorry!I thought it was you. It was actually this person http://math.stackexchange.com/users/205/shreevatsar.

Comment: @Inceptio: No worries, happens...